# Why doesn't SQL Server use my index in this SELECT ... WHERE?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan

I've created a table with a nonclustered PK (this is by design), and an additional nonclustered index on the column I'm filtering with a `WHERE` clause (`[target_user_id]`):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MP_Notification_Audit] (
    [id]                    BIGINT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [type]                  INT                NOT NULL,
    [source_user_id]        BIGINT             NOT NULL,
    [target_user_id]        BIGINT             NOT NULL,
    [discussion_id]         BIGINT             NULL,
    [discussion_comment_id] BIGINT             NULL,
    [discussion_media_id]   BIGINT             NULL,
    [patient_id]            BIGINT             NULL,
    [task_id]               BIGINT             NULL,
    [date_created]          DATETIMEOFFSET (7) CONSTRAINT [DF_MP_Notification_Audit_date_created] DEFAULT (sysdatetimeoffset()) NOT NULL,
    [clicked]               BIT                NULL,
    [date_clicked]          DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [title]                 NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [body]                  NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MP_Notification_Audit1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);

[...]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MP_Notification_Audit_TargetUser] ON [dbo].[MP_Notification_Audit]
(
    [target_user_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This table has about 11,700 rows of data in, so it should be enough to trigger the use of indexes with `WHERE` clauses.  If I `SELECT` just the column I'm filtering on, only the index is used and 133 matching rows are read - an index-only scan:

```
SELECT [target_user_id]
  FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[MP_Notification_Audit]
  WHERE [target_user_id] = 100017
```

[image: Execution plan 1]

However, as soon as I add an extra column to the `SELECT`, the index is ignored and a table scan with a predicate is done to attain the result, reading over 11,700 rows:

```
SELECT [target_user_id], [patient_id]
  FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[MP_Notification_Audit]
  WHERE [target_user_id] = 100017
```

[image: Execution plan 2]

Why is it ignoring my index in this second query?  I'd have thought it would still be more efficient to use the index to get down to 133 RIDs, then query the extra row data required, than to go through every row of the table with a predicate?  I know I can add columns to the index with `INCLUDE` with the extra fields needed in the `SELECT` clause to make it use the index again, but I'm interested as to why it doesn't still use the index in this case.

Comment: Please read about this "tipping point" in the following links https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/why-arent-those-nonclustered-indexes-being-used/  https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/ .These could give you a help ...

Comment: why not simply force it to use the index

Comment: Do you have a clone that you can share?

Comment: WorldWideDBA's answer coupled with the link above from SabinB about the "*tipping point*" should answer your question sufficiently. Just curious, why no clustered index?...I'm sure you're aware that your data will *logically* live in a heap, and you'll likely run into a lot of index fragmentation on your nonclustered indexes.

Comment: @J.D. To be honest I'm pretty confused about whether to use a clustered index or not.  Articles I've read say it's hard to impossible to know what to cluster on, and that if you cluster on the default (usually an identity column) it's generally the worst thing to cluster on - it may even be worse than a heap.

Comment: @Jez Lol, sorry that's one of the most crazy things I've read in a while. Whichever article says that clustering on the identity column "*is worse than a heap*" or "*the worst thing to cluster on*" are insane. If that was true in practice **Microsoft** wouldn't make the **primary key** the default cluster index when you create a new table. I'm pretty sure **Microsoft** (while not always perfectly right) knows more than whatever articles said otherwise. Again not a knock to you, just I can't believe you've encounter multiple articles that said the contrary. Especially in Microsoft SQL Server...

Comment: ...you should define a clustered index in probably 95% of the cases you'll run into, and there's only a few edge cases where it makes more sense not to create one (or even create any indexes for that matter). One case being when loading a large amount of data into a Staging Table (so a table won't persist the data for long or be queried directly off of). Usually defining your clustered index off of your **primary key** makes sense since that's like what you'll be using to join to in subsequent queries. I've personally had the unfortunate pleasure of working with a 3rd party database system...

Comment: ...that didn't believe in clustered indexes either, and their application that lived on top of it was very slow, they couldn't understand the concept of index fragmentation or why a heap fragments so much more easily than a B-Tree (which is what your data would logically exist in with a clustered index), and they got a lot of complaints from their customers on performance issues.

Comment: @Jez Sorry for the extended comment and rant. There's a lot of good information out there you should seek (pun intended :) out on why heaps are generally not great logical data structures in most use cases (though there are some edge cases where they do make sense). If you're not familiar with Brent Ozar, his website has a plethora of awesome information of high veracity. Here's a quick article Erik Darling wrote on the subject of some of the [performance issues](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/09/forwarded-fetches-and-bookmark-lookups/) you run into when not using a clustered index.

Comment: If you're interested, the blog post I'm remembering was [this one](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key); the main point being that the primary key being in a cluster gave a performance penalty (of 3x or 4x) when other indexes had to dereference a row that was instead of just going straight to a heap entry.  Not sure how true it is but he says he tested it.

Comment: @Jez Just got a chance to scan (heh another index pun) through the article you linked, thanks! I've briefly browsed that site before too, and will say it's ironic for a site to be called "*Use The Index*" and be advising against using indexes. All that aside, while there is **some** low level truth in the very technical and theoretical side of some of the things that article states, they're honestly only going to apply to the minority of cases in practice, and again I find a little dramatic of a perspective. For every code example it provides to explemify it's case, I can provide 10 against...

Comment: ...it. It even concludes with how SQL Server has the flexibility to define your **clustered index** more efficiently than other database systems. My recommendation is if it ain't broke don't fix it. **Clustered indexes** have been a thing for well over 20 years now, and are used in the majority of cases. If there truly was an actual performance issue as this article tries to claim, many of the other very smart database professionals (Microsoft included) would've popularized that perspective and it wouldn't be commonplace to use **clustered indexes**. Cluster on the primary key of your table...

Comment: ...natural or identity based, unless you have a much more commonplace set of fields that are queried in predicates for that table. Then consider clustering on those fields instead, with sufficient testing. Your **nonclustered indexes** will work just fine, even the ones that need to do **key lookups**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the size of your table (~11k rows), I think it would be safe to assume that SQL Server estimated that the cost of performing a seek on the non-clustered index and then potentially multiple RID lookups was more expensive than performing a table scan.

There is some evidence to support this theory within the second query plan that you pasted. I would normally expect the Query Optimiser to suggest adding a covering index for your query as you have mentioned in your post. However, it did not. This to me suggests that SQL thinks that doing so would provide little or no improvement over a full table scan.

With all that being said, I am sure that if you added more rows to the table SQL Server may change its mind and ask you to add a covering index or start performing a seek + RID lookup as you expect. If you have Query Store enabled you can always keep an eye out for queries on this table that are causing problems - if it isn't causing you a problem, I wouldn't worry about it right now.

Comment: I've tried adding a lot more data to the table, and it *still* doesn't use the index; it does a table scan, and recommends adding an index with all the select fields included. Why can't it just use the index to find the RIDs and then query them? I'm starting to wonder if it's ever worth creating indexes for performance reasons, unless the index is basically tailored to your exact SELECT query to include every field required by the query! And then they'd need extensive maintenance, being updated any time new field(s) were added.  I just want to index the `WHERE` fields!

Comment: Turns out it wasn't using the index because of the number of rows being returned.  If I change it to a query where only, say, 10 rows are returned, it does use the index combined with clustered key lookup 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of extra info:
this is the statistics for when you use table scan vs index seek+RID Lookup

**Table Scan**

```
Table 'MP_Notification_Audit'. Scan count 1, logical reads 154, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

**Index seek + RID Lookup**

```
(118 rows affected)
Table 'MP_Notification_Audit'. Scan count 1, logical reads 120, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 220 ms.
```

As can be seen, the diference in logical reads, is ~23%, but the absolute number are low, I/O system shouldnt even notice it, just 272kB.

But the difference in CPU is obvious, 220ms spent on RID lookup & Nested Loops is High.
As was said in answer, its simple. The extra IO cost was correctly estimated to be lower then the extra cost in CPU.

Comment: I tried adding a lot more data to the table, and it *still* doesn't use the index; it does a table scan, and recommends adding an index with all the `select` fields included.  Why can't it just use the index to find the RIDs and then query them?  I don't understand why SQL Server refuses to do that.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't using the index because of the number of rows being returned.  If I change it to a query where only, say, 10 rows are returned, it does use the index combined with clustered key lookup 10 times.